# Compiling Ruby error: Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed

Tags: c, ruby, unix

On OSX, after downloading the [ruby repository](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) latest commit from github and following the instructions to build, I run `make` but I get the error:

```
Failed to configure openssl. It will not be installed.
```

If I run `make check`, I get more information.

```
Skipping `gem cert` tests.  openssl not found.
...
`<class:TestGemRemoteFetcher>': uninitialized constant TestGemRemoteFetcher::OpenSSL (NameError)
```

Clearly it cannot find openssl, but I have it installed via Brew. What am I missing?

*There are many answers to this sort of question out there ([this, for example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/261914/install-ruby-2-0-with-openssl-and-readline-support)), but I can't seem to make any of the solutions work.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brew install `openssl` library as a *keg-only*. Try passing path to your openssl to your build script:

```
./configure --with-openssl-dir="$(brew --prefix openssl)"
```

Comment: Passing the path did it. It looks like openssl is installed `keg_only` by default on OSX, FWIW. I'm not sure how I would have found that flag, though. Is there a resource you could point me toward that might have helped if I had found it?

Comment: Well, the best resource would be Google -> SO :). But, usually you can get all options by running `./configure --help`. It will list software specific options/flags. If you want to see if some library is installed by brew keg-only, then run `brew info YOUR_LIB`. It will display a short info about that lib and if it is keg-only, it will have `[keg-only]` after its name.